# Error Code: 1060 Duplicate column name 'NA'

Tags: mysql, sql

I used the query as follows

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_contact` (`fname`,`code`,`contact`,`m_address`,`created_date`,`modified_date`,`row_status`) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'LULU CENT','sdfjg','NA','NA',1991-01-01,1990-01-01,'active') 
AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM tbl_contact WHERE CODE='sdfjg') LIMIT 1
```

I get the following

> Error Code: 1060
>   Duplicate column name 'NA'

My problem is I cannot add same data in two columns of my database table.

Comment: Can you share your table structure? may be you have set these fields as unique key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you select constant values without naming the columns like the following

```
SELECT 'LULU CENT','sdfjg','NA'
```

The column names of the returned result will be the same as the corresponding column values, i.e the first column name would be `LULU CENT`, the second column name would be `sdfjg`, and so on.

Since your sub query is the following

```
SELECT 'LULU CENT','sdfjg','NA','NA',1991-01-01,1990-01-01,'active'
```

The third and fourth column name would be the same (`NA`). You will get the 1060 error if you put the above query inside `SELECT * FROM (...) AS tmp` like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 'LULU CENT',
    'sdfjg',
    'NA',
    'NA',
    1991-01-01,
    1990-01-01,
    'active'
) 
AS tmp
```

You need to set a different name for each column in the sub query as below

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_contact` 
(
    `fname`,
    `code`,
    `contact`,
    `m_address`,
    `created_date`,
    `modified_date`,
    `row_status`
) 
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        'LULU CENT' AS `fname`,
        'sdfjg' AS `code`,
        'NA' AS `contact`,
        'NA' AS `m_address`,
        1991-01-01 AS `created_date`,
        1990-01-01 AS `modified_date`,
        'active' AS `row_status`
) 
AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `id` FROM tbl_contact WHERE CODE='sdfjg') LIMIT 1
```